# How to access some Server's folder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, server, file-path, layer-file, working-directory

Somehow access some file from server in QGIS is so easy just drop in your QGIS project. But some case you need access your server from QGIS "search directory" then your server is did not show up, such as for "Repair Data Source".

Answer (score 1):

This problem can handle easily by **add directory** in your **Favorites Browser**